# How can I remove/crop angle from corners of some image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I'm trying to crop an image to make it fit on my margin. One example of what I'm trying to achieve.

The original image:

[image: The original image]

After the crop:

[image: After the crop]

I already managed to crop the rectagle, but I have no idea how I can remove the corners. I tried with ctx.arc(), but I'm kinda confused with the values that I should use for x, y, radius and angle. The border-radius that I'm using depends on the screen size, but I've the value.

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve]. Take a [tour] if you missed it.

Comment: There is now a `roundRect` method in the specs, available in Chrome and for which I made [a polyfill](https://github.com/Kaiido/roundRect).

Answer (score 0):

Use `clip()` with a `Path2D` and `arcTo()`. You will have to figure out your specific values which can be done with a little math (or trial and error). Be sure to draw you image after you `clip()`

[arcTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arcTo)

[clip()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip)

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

let border = new Path2D();
border.arcTo(canvas.width, 0, canvas.width, 20, 50);
border.arcTo(canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, canvas.height, 50);
border.arcTo(0, canvas.height, 0, 20, 50);
border.arcTo(0, 0, 20, 0, 50);
ctx.clip(border);


function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
draw()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```